# List of active processes android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Using this to my View cycle only list the application process in use and not entire list of Running Processes.

I do not find running processes

`ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);`

```
 for  (RunningAppProcessInfo item : am.getRunningAppProcesses())
    {
        //
        listp.add(item.processName);
    }
```

[image]

What I found only in the course of Application

Comment: rephrase to actually ask a question?

Comment: I do not find running processes